# Only allow SVG as file type

Tags: craft3, assets, svg

I want to have an asset field which only allows `.svg`s.

To be more specific, I want to upload icons I can later import in my templates via the `svg()` command. Is this possible **without** any plugins or a custom field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [`extraFileKinds` config setting](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#extrafilekinds) like this:

```
'extraFileKinds' => [
    'svg' => [
        'label' => 'SVG',
        'extensions' => ['svg'],
    ],
],
```

On your Asset field, check the "Restrict allowed file types?" checkbox, and select "SVG" from the list.